# Flex RemoteObject + Zend AMF Server problem

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml, remoteobject, zend-amf

I am working with php, Flex and zend's AMF Server using [this](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex_php_print.html) guide. I successfully managed to connect php with Flex but after 'reconstruction' of my MySQL query I get a little bit different objects - some of their values are NULL. That confuses Flex and I get an error from my RemoteObject:
`Was expecting mx.messaging.messages.AcknowledgeMessage, but received null`
I was searching around the web, and I believe it is happening because some values are NULL, but I couldn't find appropriate solution... I hope that someone here will be able to help me =)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to fix whatever is causing null values. It's hard to say anything without seeing php/mysql part.

Comment: Of course, I also believe that it would solve my problem... But I wonder is there some simpler solution than writing lots of IF conditions in php to handle it if value is NULL...? My php/sql part is really long, but basically I retrieve values from relational database using LEFT JOIN syntax and I format values to php object and send that object to Flex...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is a null value - I suspect you have an error in your PHP code, and it's getting a null instead of a AcknowledgeMessage because the PHP is erroring out before it sends anything back.  Have you tried running it directly (i.e., not from Flex)?

I've found Charles Proxy (http://www.charlesproxy.com/) an invaluable tool for debugging such issues.  You have to pay for it ($50), but the amount I've saved on Excedrin Migraine has paid for it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for help, I am outside of town at the moment, but as I remember, when I use var_dump in PHP, my object looks as I expect it... Inside of it, I get some strings and arrays. Some of the arrays contain NULL values. I don't see it as problem for PHP to handle NULL values... I have some ideas now so I will try to do it when I get back... Thanks!